# Can't target certain XML elements with regex

Tags: xml, regex, preg-match-all

I've been using regular expressions to target text between XML elements and it works fine with most elements in the XML tree. However, the elements that are clickable/expandable when viewing the raw XML document in the web browser don't get targeted by regex. When I use preg_match in PHP I just get an empty array.

Now, I know works but just to be clear, here it is:

```
$contents "random fetched xml doc";
$regex = '/<element>(.*?)<\/element>/';
preg_match_all($regex, $contents, $output);

print_r($output);
```

**Please note:** I have googled the issue and found a lot of results saying you shouldn't parse XML with regex. I am **not** interested in learning how to parse XML in general, I'm learning a technique for scraping data from websites, and I'm just practicing on a website containing XML pages, since they provide intuitive delimiters (the XML tags).

My question is simply: How do I modify my regex to target the expandable XML elements?

**EDIT: SOLVED ISSUE**
The question was based on false premises. The problem has nothing to do with XML, but rather that my regular expression matched anything between the elements *except* linebreaks. After adding /s at the end of my expression, it works like a charm. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use some XML parser. There plenty of them http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xml+parser&mode=all

Comment: And http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0014/LibXML.pod as well. Regex usually used for different needs.

Comment: It would probably help if you provided a short example and noted which elements your current approach works for an which it doesn't work for.  The phrase "the elements that are clickable/expandable ... in the web browser" means nothing to at least this reader (browser behavior is not specified by the XML spec, and in all the browsers I know, if any elements are expandable all are).  Impossible to tell what's going wrong without more information.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to use them and I would much rather just find out how I can modify my code above.

Comment: You could possibly add that as an answer, to don't leave this unanswered. `:P`

Comment: Oh ok, still learning how to behave on stackoverflow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a while. The question was based on false premises. The problem has nothing to do with XML, but rather that my regular expression matched anything between the elements except linebreaks. After adding /s at the end of my expression, it works like a charm. Thanks for your time!